# Equivalence between Lambda Calculus [Church] and Computable Partial Functions [Godel]

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus, computation-models

In order to show that Lambda calculus and Turing machines are equivalent it is sufficient to show that you can simulate one in the other [both ways].

We can observe it in action. Can one do the same on general recursive functions [ie mathematical functions as defined by Godel]

Are there any reference reading materials?

Comment: See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/recursive-functions.html for a note on recursive function in the λ-calculus

Answer (score 0):

To simulate the lambda calculus on a Turing machine, all you need to do is build an interpreter for the lambda calculus.  That is easy.  If you want a reference, I recommend [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs).  In general, what are describing falls within computability theory, so I recommend studying a good textbook on that subject.  There are [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/962414/14578).

Comment: The question already acknowledges that it is possible to simulate lambda calculus on turing machines. I want to know how to simulate lambda calculus by using mathematical functions in the theory of general recursive functions [partial recursive functions]

Comment: @RFV, I encourage you to edit the question to make it clearer what you already know and what you are asking, then.  I didn't realize you already know this and that you were asking that.  I think it would help to state those explicitly in the question.